# How to use `readableContentGuide` with accessory view on a custom cell?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitableview

I created a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`. I want to align the edges of my subview to the `readableContentGuide` anchors:

```
let guide = contentView.readableContentGuide
myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
```

[image]

This works as expected until I add an accessory view, which causes the layout to be off.

```
accessoryType = .discloseIndicator
```

[image]

On the default cells the layout works correctly:

[image]

I'm curious to know if this is a UIKit bug or if there's a different way I should be doing this?

I came up with a temporary workaround where I attach my subview to the default text label, which seems to work but of course I'd rather not.

```
textLabel?.text = " "
myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textLabel!.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
```

[image]

ps: the blue box shows the frame of the `cell.contentView` (via the View debugger)

Answer (score 0):

1. Set `cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth` to `true` on Table View

```
tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = true
```

2. Alternatively you can checkmark `Follow Readable Width` on Table View in the Interface Builder